# Condição não contém no DataGridView

Tags: c#

Boa noite.

Preciso fazer uma comparação entre dois DataGridView's e exibir em um terceiro DataGridView, as linhas do primeiro que não está contido no segundo.

Abaixo, a imagem dos dois DataGridView's que preciso comprar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que, no primeiro DataGridView, há uma linha com o documento 63989, e no segundo DataGridView, este registro está faltando.

Meu objetivo então, é exibir esta linha que está faltando em um terceiro DataGridView para que o usuário saiba qual documento está faltando.

Tudo que consegui fazer no momento foi o contrário, exibir as linhas que coincidem nos dois DataGridView's.

Segue o código:

```
private void btAnalisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (radioButtonNotasAusentesConsisaNet.Checked == true)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewSefaz.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             for (int index = 0; index < dataGridViewConsisaNet.Rows.Count; index++)
            {
                if (dataGridViewSefaz.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(dataGridViewConsisaNet.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridViewAnalise.Rows.Insert(0, dataGridViewSefaz.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridViewSefaz.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), dataGridViewSefaz.Rows[i].Cells[24].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como posso proceder?

Comment: não relacionado à pergunta mas, o que você está usando pra essa interface do datagridview ? obrigado

Comment: Sinceramente nada. Eu apenas alterei suas propriedades.

Comment: esse não é o visual padrão do controle, por isso a pergunta, não está usando nenhum componente externo pra isso ?

Comment: Sim, este é o controle padrão do DataGridView, tudo que fiz foi editar suas propriedades. Caso queira, posso disponibilizar para download.

Comment: ficou bem legal, não se preocupe a curiosidade era saber se era algo externo mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: Obrigado. Realmente é importante para mim receber todo feedback possível sobre meu projeto.

Comment: Sobre o meu problema, você teria alguma solução? Sinceramente, não sei o que faço.

Comment: Faça a lógica nas classes, utilize o datagridview só para exibir. Coloca a classe que você usa para as notas que tento te ajudar... Estou sem tempo,mas vou tentando

Comment: O problema é que estas Grids recebem dados diretamente de uma planilha do excel. Apenas a segunda Grid utiliza uma classe para organizar melhor os dados. Por isso tento fazer a análise diretamente nos DataGridView's. Pensei em fazer isso utilizando Lists, pois há um Método chamado Except. Mas não estudei a fundo como funciona.

Comment: O primeiro passo é criar as classes que representam as linhas, depois trabalhar com as listas. Mostra o código que você preenche os grids

Comment: Segue o link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KT1br1pIgwWvdGTar_vHfDV89ssrO9XE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Assim sem testar, só com Notepad++ mesmo, penso que isto resolveria:

```
private void btAnalisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButtonNotasAusentesConsisaNet.Checked)
    {
        foreach(var dataRow in dataGridViewSefaz.Rows)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow.Cells[2].Value);
            var notExists = dataGridViewConsisaNet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().
                Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Value) != value).
                Select(x => new DataGridViewRow() { x.Cells[2].Value, x.Cells[3].Value, x.Cells[24].Value });

            if(notExists.Length > 0)
                dataGridViewAnalise.Rows.AddRange(notExists);
        }
    }
}
```

Se não funcionar (visto que não testei), pode sempre alterar a forma como a lista `notExists` é construída e é inserida na 3ª grelha:

```
var notExists = dataGridViewConsisaNet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().
    Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Value) != value);

foreach(var dataRow in notExists)
    dataGridViewAnalise.Rows.Add(new object[] { x.Cells[2].Value, x.Cells[3].Value, x.Cells[24].Value });
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela atenção a minha questão. Eu analisei seu código e existem alguns problemas de sintaxe. Fiz uma breve correção e o adaptei.

Answer (score 0):

Ficou assim:

```
if (radioButtonNotasAusentesConsisaNet.Checked == true)
{
 foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataGridViewSefaz.Rows)
 {
  int value = Convert.ToInt32(linha.Cells[2].Value);
  var notExists = dataGridViewConsisaNet.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Value) != value);
  foreach (var dataRow in notExists)
  {
   dataGridViewAnalise.Rows.Add(new object[] { dataRow.Cells[2].Value, dataRow.Cells[3].Value, dataRow.Cells[24].Value });
  }
 }
}
```

Porém, ao rodar, é exibida esta exceção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, inverti as DataGridViews no código para ficar assim:

```
if (radioButtonNotasAusentesConsisaNet.Checked == true)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataGridViewConsisaNet.Rows)
                {
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(linha.Cells[2].Value);
                    var notExists = dataGridViewSefaz.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Value) != value);

                    foreach (var dataRow in notExists)
                    {
                        dataGridViewAnalise.Rows.Add(new object[] { dataRow.Cells[2].Value, dataRow.Cells[3].Value, dataRow.Cells[24].Value });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Mas, o que ocorre é que ele repete os valores na terceira Grid. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sinceramente, não sei o que posso fazer para corrigir isso.

Answer (score 0):

Você primeiro tem que pensar no problema sem a exibição dos dados, depois de resolvido utilize o DataGridView apenas para exibição.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo, espero que ajude a entender o problema:

Primeiro você precisa definir um objeto da sua NotaFiscal:

```
public class NotaFiscal
{
    public string Chave {get;set;}
    public string Emitente {get;set;}
    public decimal Total {get;set;}
}
```

Depois vai obter os dados nesse formato, não importa se vem do banco de dados, do excel, ou de outra fonte:

```
public static List<NotaFiscal> GetNotasExcel()
{
    List<NotaFiscal> notas = new List<NotaFiscal>();

    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "123456ABC", Emitente = "Empresa A", Total = 10 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "223456DEF", Emitente = "Empresa B", Total = 20 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "423456JKL", Emitente = "Empresa D", Total = 40 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "623456PQR", Emitente = "Empresa F", Total = 60 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "723456STU", Emitente = "Empresa G", Total = 70 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "823456VWX", Emitente = "Empresa H", Total = 80 });


    return notas;
}

public static List<NotaFiscal> GetNotasConsisaNet()
{
    List<NotaFiscal> notas = new List<NotaFiscal>();

    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "123456ABC", Emitente = "Empresa A", Total = 10 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "223456DEF", Emitente = "Empresa B", Total = 20 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "323456GHI", Emitente = "Empresa C", Total = 30 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "423456JKL", Emitente = "Empresa D", Total = 40 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "523456MNO", Emitente = "Empresa E", Total = 50 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "623456PQR", Emitente = "Empresa F", Total = 60 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "723456STU", Emitente = "Empresa G", Total = 70 });
    notas.Add(new NotaFiscal(){ Chave = "823456VWX", Emitente = "Empresa H", Total = 80 });


    return notas;
}
```

Então você armazena os dados em listas, para que possa trabalhar com eles:

```
List<NotaFiscal> notasExcel =  GetNotasExcel();
List<NotaFiscal> notasConsisaNet =  GetNotasConsisaNet();
```

Agora sim, pode achar os dados, nas condições que quiser. Aproveitando seu caso, fiz um exemplo para selecionar todas as notas que estão na "ConsisaNET" e não estão no arquivo Excel:

```
List<string> chavesExcept = notasConsisaNet.Select(x => x.Chave).Except(notasExcel.Select(x=>x.Chave)).ToList();
```

> Repare que tive que selecionar todas as chaves (string) para comparar com as chaves da outra lista. Isso porque, se você compara dois objetos eles serão comparados pela instância, então mesmo que os dados são iguais, são instancias diferentes e não seriam retornados nessa cláusula.

Com a lista de chaves, agora você pode selecionar as notas desejadas (se necessário):

```
List<NotaFiscal> notasExcept = notasConsisaNet.Where(x => chavesExcept.Contains(x.Chave)).ToList();
```

**Pronto!** Você já tem todos os dados que precisa em memória. Basta exibi-los:

```
dataGridViewExcept.DataSource = notasExcept;
dataGridViewNotasExcel.DataSource = notasExcel;
dataGridViewNotasConsisa.DataSource = notasConsisaNet;
```

---

Fiz um exemplo no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cCfeAi)

> Espero que ajude a resolver o problema. Recomendo que acesse e leia o **[Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)**, pois é importante para saber como participar da comunidade e elaborar as perguntas. Você ainda pode melhorar sua pergunta deixando-a mais específica e clara, assim ganha reputação e normalmente os votos negativos são retirados.

Comment: Vou testar agora na parte da noite e logo que possível, deixo meu feedback. Mas já quero agradecer pela atenção dada a minha questão.